# How to fix setting source window font of Visual Studio 6 on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, registry, visual-c++-6

In Visual Studio 6 installed on Windows 7 (Home Premium 64-bit SP1), I cannot see or change the font for source windows via Tools > Options...

Tools > Options..., Format tab, Category: Source Windows, yields Font: (blank) with empty list, Size (blank) with empty list.

It appeared that the relevant registry hive was missing:

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\DevStudio\6.0\Format]

Importing this registry hive from an existing installation does change the font as desired, but still does not show it nor let me change these settings via Tools > Options... .

Is there a proper solution so that the Format options work as they should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a look at an installation on a WinXP machine and got it working by adding the following keys to the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\DevStudio\6.0\Format]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\DevStudio\6.0\Format\Output Window]
"FontFace"="Consolas"
"FontSize"=dword:0000000c

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\DevStudio\6.0\Format\Source Window]
"FontFace"="Consolas"
"FontSize"=dword:0000000c
```

The above lines set the Source and Output window's font to Consolas with a size of 12 points.
It's an export by `regedit` so you can put it into a `.reg` file and import by opening that file in Explorer.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall that when you install VS6 on Win7 the installer reports "There are known issues with this program." and asks if you want to go ahead regardless.

Maybe this is one of the issues.

Comment: Hi Richard, yes let's declare it so ;) Still useful (and needed) though. Cheers, Martin.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265715%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

VS6 Windows 7 works best if launched in virtual pc XP mode. It's virtual machine, very convinient.